# Not able to convert from string to int in java

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have simple program which will convert string to int using `parseInt` but not able to convert getting `NumberFormatException`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String invoiceNo = "3466002000";
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(invoiceNo));
}
```

Exception Trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3466002000"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.utils.ExcelFileUtil.main(ExcelFileUtil.java:159)
```

Comment: `3466002000` is not an integer literal. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`. Try using `Long.praseLong(...)` instead.

Comment: Try a long int.

Answer (score 1):

The value `3466002000` is too big to parse it to `int`. Use `long` instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String invoiceNo = "3466002000";
    System.out.println(Long.parseLong(invoiceNo));
}
```